# div background does not show properly in chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, background

I'm using float: left; and float: right; to put two div-containers in one row, the left one holds an input bar, the right one holds a small background image (search button).

It's showing fine in Opera & Firefox, MSIE 9.0+ but when I view it in chrome the right container's background image is slightly off position (shifted downwards by a few pixels).

I set the background color to red to highlight the issue:
[screenshot](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/7387/chromekk.jpg)

index.php outtake:

```
<div class="header_inner_right">
    <form id="search_bar" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkSearchQuery();">
            <div class="left">
                <input id="search_field" name="q" type="text" value="Search riddim, artist, tune, label and producer" 
                    onfocus="searchFieldValue_onFocus();" onblur="searchFieldValue_onBlur();">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input id="search_button" src="images/search_button.gif" type="submit" value="">
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

index_chrome.css (used if php script detects chrome browser):

```
@charset "ISO-8859-1";

#search_bar {
    width: 450px;
    height: 37px;
    background-color: red
}

#search_bar #search_field {
    border: 0px;
    width: 365px;
    height: 37px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/search_field.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    background-color: #ffffff
}

#search_bar #search_button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    height: 37px;
    width: 45px;
    background-image: url(../images/search_button.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

How to fix it and adjust the y-position of the magnifying-glass background image so its perfectly aligned with the left div's background image and fully concealing the red background of the right div container?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/YcraM/

Sorry, forgot about JSFiddle!

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com/) with the appropriate resources, so that we can edit it on our machines?

Comment: you can use `display:inline-block` css for your divs to put them in one row.

Comment: Just added the JSFiddle link, curious about this issue but probably just caused by my lack of experiance with cross-browser-css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer you want to hear, but it's pretty much impossible to make most input elements look identical cross browsers. I urge you to fashion the submit button from a `div` element. Example:

```
<div class="left">
    <input id="search_field" name="q" type="text" value="Search riddim, artist, tune, label and producer" 
        onfocus="searchFieldValue_onFocus();" onblur="searchFieldValue_onBlur();">
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div id="search_button"></div>
</div>
```

Style the div with css to your liking - remember to use the `:hover` and `:active` pseudo classes. Then, using for example jQuery, make it functional like this:

```
$('#search_button').on('click', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Well, I'm open for any solutions as this issue really messed with me yesterday. Thanks for the answer, your solution with javascript and a div-container works like a charm. The only problem left now, I noticed the same problem occurs on top of the search_field [LIKE HERE](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/3172/msie8und7.jpg) if you view the website in MSIE7 or MSIE8. Is there a chance I can use a div as input field?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it in Chrome 21 and FF 14, it seems setting `line-height:0px;` fixes the issue.

```
div.right {
    float: right;
    line-height:0px;
}    
div.left {
    float: left;
    line-height:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YcraM/3/

I haven't tested in other browsers, so forgive me if this isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `float:right` (or left) to `#search_bar #search_button`, that fix the issue as well

Comment: Thanks, I have now fixed all issues using float: right for the search_field and search_button and Codemonkey's suggestion to use a div with a JS submit instead of an input tag.